# Add superscript and subscript exactly at the same X axis in SVG

Tags: svg, text, subscript, superscript

I want to place superscript and subscript in the same place for a text, in SVG. This is a requirement in mathematical and chemical equations. There seems to be no option for such a requirement in SVg.

The requirement is when a superscript and subscript are placed beside some text their x value of origin must be identical. These super and subscripts may appear before or after a text and the requirement applies to both cases. First I tried placing them using the  element of SVG with x & y coordinates, and it works very well (attachment 1). However, the problem arises when programmatically finding x & y coordinates for each element.

Then I tried  element with  and applying dx, which also works well but dx varies with the font size. Before I try implementing a custom solution I would like to know if there is a better solution.

I have attached the code I used and sample images.

My first attempt.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Code that works well with x & y coordinates for all elements -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
    viewBox="0 0 64 64" style="stroke-width:0;fill:black;font-size:24px;font-family:Sans-serif">
    <text x="17" y="50" font-size="48px">B</text>
    <text x="4" y="22">A</text>
    <text x="43.59" y="22" font-size="36px">±</text>
    <text x="4" y="63">Z</text>
    <text x="43.59" y="63">C</text>
</svg>`

Second attempt with recommended elements of SVG

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Textbook recommended for super and subscripts, unacceptable result -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
    viewBox="0 0 128 128" style="stroke-width:0;fill:black;font-size:24px;font-family:Sans-serif">
    <text x="1" y="64" font-size="24px" letter-spacing="-4">
        <tspan baseline-shift="super" font-size="18px" >A</tspan>
        <tspan baseline-shift="sub" font-size="18px" text-anchor="end">Z</tspan>
        B
        <tspan baseline-shift="super" font-size="18px" >±</tspan>
        <tspan baseline-shift="sub" font-size="18px">C</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>`

Third attempt with negative dx for tspan elements.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Code that works well with minus values for dx of subscripts -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
    viewBox="0 0 128 128" style="stroke-width:0;fill:black;font-size:24px;font-family:Sans-serif">
    <text x="1" y="64" font-size="24px" letter-spacing="-4">
        <tspan baseline-shift="super" font-size="18px" >A</tspan>
        <tspan baseline-shift="sub" dx="-10" font-size="18px" text-anchor="end">Z</tspan>
        B
        <tspan baseline-shift="super" font-size="18px" >±</tspan>
        <tspan baseline-shift="sub" dx="-10" font-size="18px">C</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>`

There's no error messages. Expected and actual results are shown in attached images.

1. Result with x & y coordinates for all SVG elements

[image: Result with x & y coordinates for all SVG elements]

2. Result with the recommended text & tspan elements and baseline-shift values of super and sub

[image: Result with the recommended text & tspan elements and baseline-shift values of super and sub]

3. Result with text & tspan and minus dx values for subscripts
[image: Result with <text> & <tspan> and minus dx values for subscripts]

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong technology and you should be using mathml instead.

Comment: This is similar to a question I asked before but that was pure HTML question where as this one is a SVG question. There are some similarities between HTML & SVG coding but the results in this case vary.

Answer (score 2):

If you continue with SVGs, then one suggestion that might be useful to you, is to use `em` units for your subscript and superscript coordinate offsets.  That way, they will be independent of the font size you set for the main character.

See the following example, where the only difference between the two SVGs is the `font-size` CSS setting.

```css
#one {
  width: 250px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
}


#two {
  width: 250px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="one" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
    <text x="17" y="50">B</text>
    <text x="17" y="50" font-size="0.5em" dx="-0.55em" dy="-1.2em">A</text>
    <text x="17" y="50" font-size="0.75em" dx="0.74em" dy="-0.78em">±</text>
    <text x="17" y="50" font-size="0.5em" dx="-0.55em" dy="0.55em">Z</text>
    <text x="17" y="50" font-size="0.5em" dx="1.1em" dy="0.55em">C</text>
</svg>


<svg id="two" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
    <text x="17" y="50">B</text>
    <text x="17" y="50" font-size="0.5em" dx="-0.55em" dy="-1.2em">A</text>
    <text x="17" y="50" font-size="0.75em" dx="0.74em" dy="-0.78em">±</text>
    <text x="17" y="50" font-size="0.5em" dx="-0.55em" dy="0.55em">Z</text>
    <text x="17" y="50" font-size="0.5em" dx="1.1em" dy="0.55em">C</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's a cool solution with a limited applicability. It's good for most symbols but falls short for characters like U (Uranium) and W (Tungsten). For 2 letter symbols like Ca (Calcium) it's even worse. I think I can still use it for the super/sub before the symbol though.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think this solution is still in the right direction. The dx values for ± and the subscript C are the only issues now. I could use bbox to get the point at which the base symbols end and programmatically calculate the starting point in PX values for ± and C. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: How's the font size related to 'em' in this context? If 1em equals 48px (as in the first case) does 1.1em means 52.8px? I also read this "The em is simply the font size. In an element with a 2in font, 1em thus means 2in." in https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html. However, if I replace 1.1em with 52.8px it doesn't work the way font size in px and em are related. Is there a good explanation for this apparent discrepancy please?

Comment: @VelusamyVelu "1.1em" and "52.8px" should give exactly the same result. Here's an example. The green and blue text is precisely overlaid. https://jsfiddle.net/exna5g0h/

Comment: I appreciate your response. But sorry, I wasn't fully clear on my question. I was using em and px to set the dx (dx='1.1em' & dx='52.8px') and found them not the same. The requirement as stated in my original question needs a better solution.

Comment: The two values will be identical as long as the `font-size` is identical for both.  But they aren't in this case.  Note that for the last text line, the `font-size` is set to `"0.5em"`. So the `dx="1.1em` is referring to the half size text.  So it is `1.1 * 24px`.  Not `1.1 * 48px`.  So it would need to be `dx="26.4px"` instead. https://jsfiddle.net/oceps7ma/